# Filtering safe primes for Diffie Hellman on OpenVPN

Tags: openssl, diffie-hellman, openvpn, openssh

When creating Diffie Hellman parameters for OpenSSH, there's a two-step process which looks like this to generate and filter secure primes for Diffie Hellman key exchange:

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096 -G dh4096-insecure
ssh-keygen -f dh4096-insecure -T dh4096
```

When reading the OpenVPN documentation, they recommend generating DH parameters like so:

```
openssl dhparam 2048 -out dh2048.pem
```

Is there a way to filter these primes for safety before using them with OpenVPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL does filter the primes it generates and then outputs a single one.

You should just **not** use the `-dsaparam` option.

Source: [manpage](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Dhparam(1))

Answer (score 1):

A safe prime p is a prime such that p = 2 q + 1, with q also a prime.
Actually, there are two ways to find safe primes:  one is to generate a prime (that is, a random number, and apply a primality test to its uneven successors) p ; then calculate q = (p - 1)/2 and do a second primality test on q.

However, one can also generate first a prime q (random number, and primality test on uneven successors), calculate p = 2 q + 1, and do a primality test on p.

If both primality tests are reliable, I would think that both procedures are equivalent.  I don't know what procedure is more prone to "doctored non-safe primes".  In any case, one can easily do such generation one-self.